# How to get value of input field from "if block" in django framework?

Tags: django

I need compare the value between an input and a context variable in a html.

How can I do it?

```
{% for admin in administradores %}
   {% if admin.id == *INPUT_VALUE* %}
      <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nombre</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
               <input value="{{admin.nombre}}" type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre..." pattern="^[a-zA-zñÑ]+(\s*[a-zA-zñÑ]*)*$" title="solo se pueden digitar letras" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: What's that *INPUT_VALUE* suppose to be? I hope not the one that user suppose to provide, right?

Comment: something like this '<input type="hidden" value="12" name="id" />

Comment: Ok, where do you get the `value="12"` from? Is it stored in database?

Comment: it's an id returned from another context variable

Answer (score 0):

If that context variable is called `foo` that you want compare your `admin.id` with, than you can just put inside the `if` tag:

```
{% if admin.id == foo %}
    ....
{% endif %}
```

it will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remenber this, when you use the template django system is for rendering a HTML code that you will send to the browser, so django won't help you (much) to get a value in an input. Django just fill the code with the template language and perform the operations (template tags and other operations) he found on the document {{ }} or {% %}. If you have that input value in a context variable, you will use as normal

```
{% if admin.id == foo %}
```

but if you can't reach that variable in the view when you are rendering that template, you will have to use a context processor to get that variable in any of your templates...